# To repeat the key as much as the length of the plain entered in Python

Tags: python, encryption

```
plaintext:sunny day
key:like

sunny day
likelikel   <--What I want to get
```

1)I would like to receive the plain text and key through input value to implement the classic cipher now. Compared to the plain text, I would like to make the key value repeat as long as the plain text as above.

```
for t in range(len(plaintext)):
    letterspace = ord(plain[t]) - ord(keyletter[t])
```

2)Afterwards, we will work to find the distance between 's' and 'l', 'u' and 'i'..(continue) However, there is also a problem with this task. This makes indexerror: string index out of range error.

I want to know how to deal with these related two problems. It seems that the answer 1 and 2 are connected, so I post them together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple strategies to solve this.

You could repeat the initial key to get a repeated key which is at least as large as the plaintext:

```
keyletter = keyletter * math.ceil(len(plain)/len(keyletter))
# the following code is not changed
for t in range(len(plaintext)):
    letterspace = ord(plain[t]) - ord(keyletter[t])
```

You could also use a way to wrap `t` when it reaches the end of `keyletter`. This can be done with counters, but the easiest would be the use of the modulo operator:

```
for t in range(len(plaintext)):
    letterspace = ord(plain[t]) - ord(keyletter[t % len(keyletter)])
```